# Check values in a range.Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, range

I want to check in Excel IF one value in one cell is lower in the following cells that comes after that cell. I have 54 cells with values. First I compare value in cell I1 with value in I2 to I54. If I find a value that is lower than I1 in cells I2 to I54 I want the text to be Check otherwise ok. 
Then when I1 is done I want to check for cell I2 if there are any values in I3-I54 that is lower then I2. And so on to finaly check for I53 compared to just I54. I tried this
 =IF(I1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data looks something like this:

```
   I
1  30
2  67
3  53
4  36
5  75
6  63
7  53
8  49
9  40
10 38
```

What I think you mean is that in I1 you want a formula that will tell you whether any of the below data (I2 - I54) is less than I1, if it is display "Check" otherwise display "Ok". You then want this to be the same in I2, but working out whether any of the data below I2 is less than the value in I2.

If this is correct then you could add a formula like the below in J1.

```
 =IF(MIN(I2:$I$54)<I1,"Check","Ok")
```

By adding this in column J, you would end up with the following for the above data:

```
   I    J
1  30   Ok
2  67   Check
3  53   Check
4  36   Ok
5  75   Check
6  63   Check
7  53   Check
8  49   Check
9  40   Check
10 38   Ok
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, can you please accept this as the answer

Comment: But one thing in your example; in your table it should be ok for I5. 75 because 75 is greater than the rest in in I6-I10.  The same for I6 and I7,I8,I9 and I10. The rest is check. Do you agree?

Comment: Sorry not I10 that the last one but you understand.

Comment: I see what you mean, but in your question you say that if it finds a number below that is less than it, display "check" - so here 63 is lower than 75, so "check" is displayed

Comment: Thats fine! but I2 and I3 has values below that is higher, thats my point. I think the code will work! Thanks again.

Comment: Now I have tried the formula and sorry it doesn´t work.

Comment: For more clarity; Want I want  to do is this: If I dont have a list that have falling values I want a signal that tells me "Check this value out". So if I have values I1:100, I2:99, I3:98, I4:97, I5:96, I6:95, I7:98 I want in column J3,J4,J5 and J6: "Check this out", because I have a value in I7 that is higher than the above cells in I3 to I6. I hope this explain what I want tot accomplish.

Comment: =IF(MAX(I2:$I$54)>I3;"Check";"Ok") Thats the one. But I give right Ben!